# graphicspath causes rmarkdown complilation failure

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, pandoc

I am working in R Studio, using rmarkdown to create beamer slides. When I declare multiple graphics paths (using `\graphicspath{{"path1"},{"path2"}})` in the `header_includes` chunk, my Beamer PDF does not compile, giving a "failed to compile" error. A minimum working example is given below.

I am revisiting slides I created about 10 months ago - they worked fine then.

Declaring no path works:

```
---
title: A plea for help
author: Minimum reproducible example
output: beamer_presentation
---

## A plea for help

Help much appreciated
```

So does declaring only a single path:

```
---
title: A plea for help
author: Minimum reproducible example
output: beamer_presentation
header-includes:
- \graphicspath{{"C:/Users/me"}}
---

## A plea for help

Help much appreciated
```

But multiple paths fails:

```
---
title: A plea for help
author: Minimum reproducible example
output: beamer_presentation
header-includes:
- \graphicspath{{"C:/Users/me"},{"C:/Users/you"}}
---

## A plea for help

Help much appreciated
```

Comment: Should there be a comma? I’m not sure as I am on phone but just saw [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499643/include-figure-with-path-relative-to-graphicspath)

Comment: The syntax is wrong, remove the comma